# Codeigniter - Missing argument 1 for MainController

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a error like this in my view :

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for MainController::statistic()
>
> Filename: front-end/MainController.php
>
> Line Number: 66

here is my **controller** :

```
public function statistic($id_rider)// this is line 66
    {
        $template['menuActive'] = 'index';
        $template['menuLoggedIn'] = $this->menuLoggedIn;

        $this->load->view('front-end/template/header', $template);
        $this->load->view('front-end/detail-statistic');
        $this->load->view('front-end/template/footer', $template);
    }
```

And for the `$id_rider` are taken from the **view** like this:

```
<?php echo '<a href="'.base_url().'statistic/'.$rider['id_rider'].'" class="btn btn-3d btn-primary">Statistic</a>'?></div>
```

But the `$id_rider` is shown on the url:

[image]

i don't know what causing it, maybe it because i use nested `foreach()` in my **view** to get the data, something like this :

```
<?php foreach($teams_list_data as $team) {

  foreach($riders_list_data as $rider) {
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a default value in your function argument like this:

```
public function statistic( $id_rider = '' ) or
public function statistic( $id_rider = false )
```

And then var_dump( $id_rider ) to check if it's actually passed